# swagger-ui hangs on big responses

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

One of my endpoints returns a JSON (not huge, around 2MB). Trying to run GET on this endpoint in `swagger-ui` results in the browser hanging for a few minutes. After this time, it finally displays the JSON.

Is there a way to define that the response shouldn't be rendered but provided as a file to download instead?

I'm using OpenAPI 3, and I tried the following:

```yaml
content:
    application/json:
        schema:
            type: string
            format: binary
```

taken from [the documentation.](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/#response-that-returns-a-file) Still, swagger-ui renders the response.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3832, https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6206, https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6202

Comment: saw these ones, so it seems there is no solution for now

Comment: Check https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3832#issuecomment-860730706 - by setting the Content-Disposition header, it is possible to control the download behaviour. Works for us.

Comment: Problem is known for more than 5 years know. Still not fixed :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Lex45x](https://github.com/Lex45x) proposes [in this github issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3832#issuecomment-942470952) to disable syntax highlighting. In ASP.Net Core you can do this with

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(config =>
{
    config.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems["syntaxHighlight"] = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["activated"] = false
    };
});
```

This significantly improves render performance.

Comment: How do I add the `syntaxHighlight` false for the OpenAPI Quarkus service? I am facing a problem so I tried a couple of things but still not working. Can you please have a look at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73984320/7584240

Comment: I love you, Peter. You helped me soo much.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent to PeterB's answer on newer versions of NSwag (using `UseSwaggerUI3`) looks like this:

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUi3(settings =>
{
   settings.AdditionalSettings.Add("syntaxHighlight", false);
});
```

Comment: How do I add the `syntaxHighlight` false for the OpenAPI Quarkus service? I am facing a problem so I tried a couple of things but still not working. Can you please have a look at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73984320/7584240

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent in spring-boot, if using SpringDoc-openapi, is to add this to your application.yml

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    syntaxHighlight:
      activated: false
```

Here's the link to the official docs: https://springdoc.org/#swagger-ui-properties